# FFT Image to Measure Similarities

Tags: java, image, image-processing, fft

Ok I'm writing a small Java app that accepts two images as inputs, compares them, then gives a quantitative output as a measure of similarity (eg. 50% similar).

To my understanding FFT is a good way to measure similarity of two images. But I can't for the love of god figure out how to code/implement it.

So far I've implemented another function which basically gives me two histograms (one for each image). All I need now is to write a method that will FFT an image and give me a quantifiable outcome.

Can anyone help me out with this? I'd really like to see some sample codes, if not at least a point in the right direction. Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Similarity is not an exact term. For example: if you have circle, and an ellipse are they similar? They are both round objects, so in this sense they are - but if we want to filter out circles only they are not. You will have to define a measure (or measures - for example roundness, intensity distribution, size, orientation, number of objects, euler number, etc.), than calculate it for each image. The similarity of the two images will be (some kind of) distance between the two calculated values. This could be euclidean distance (for two real measures), or some kind of error function (RMS for intensity distributions).

You will have to choose to which transforms should your measure stay invariant (is the rotated image similar to the original? If yes, simple fourier transform is not appropriate).

Measuring similarity of an image is hard, if you have to do that I would read about [image stitching](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=70092). If you just need to distinguish BLOB-s, first try to calculate some simple measures (I recommend calculating moments - area, orientation; read [K-means clusteing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering)), or 1D fourier transform of the distance of the contour from the center of the mass (whic is a little bit more difficult).

Comment: If you would like to use histograms as a similarity measure, I think RMSD could be a good measure of similarity. But I think histograms are not too robust measures.

Comment: The domain of images I have is strictly restricted to images of cars from the same angle. Only different lighting, As far as orientation and scale goes, variations are very minimal.

I'm also aware that histograms are very general as a white room can have the same histogram as a snowy scenery. These are simply additional functions of my program.

To my understanding the FFT provides a decent measure of image similarity so I'd like to know how I can implement that and get a similarity measurement, preferably in the form of a percentage derived from the result of the FFT somehow

Answer (score 1):

Before you attempt to code up a 2DFT, you should fully understand the math behind it. flolo is correct that you can compute it by first doing a 1D FFT on the rows and columns and then combining the results, but I have no reason to believe the L_inf norm is the best way to convert them to a metric, since it completely skips the usual combining step to create the full 2DFT. Take a look at http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/Image_Processing/node6.html at the very bottom of the page.

That said, there may be better ways to compare images that don't require comparing 2D arrays of information. For instance, PCA (Principal Component Analysis, which is just a matter of running SVD {Singular Value Decomposition} on your images after mean-centering them, though I'd take a  look at the wikipedia article on it first) will give you a 1D vector which you could then apply some L_p norm to directly to compare, although in this case, i would use something like sum(min(a_i/b_i , b_i/a_i))/length(a), where a and b are the 1D vectors you got from the transform.

Answer (score 0):

There are many good sites with code for a fft on an 1-D array of values. You just apply this fft row by row on your image. And afterwards you do fft columnwise on the results.

Now you need a metric to get from the resulting transformed image, my suggestion would be to try the max-norm (L_inf). That is max_{x,y}{fft2d(imag1)[x,y] - fft2d(imag2)[x,y]}.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that. Someone just told me to check out JavaCV. Do you know if that could be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if it is likely that one image is a quick edit of another for something like DRM of stock photography then check the percentages of a normalized color palette within probable regions. If they match within an THRESHOLD for a NUMBER_OF_TEST_COLORS in any one of a number of TEST_REGIONS within the image then you have a "suspect"... you still need a human to check the suspects. But this is a quick and dirty way to find many of the image re-sizers, horiz/vert flippers, and background color changers, file format changers, and other subtle variations... of course "normalizing the colors" to a quantized palette is an art unto itself. I would recommend quantizing images into nearest "web safe" colors for practicality.

I'm a blue collar garbage man in comparison to a mathematician, but garbage men are quite practical! I have had good success with this kind of approach in grouping similar images and search by color applications.